# Difference between "at rest" and "not in motion"

Tags: word-usage

Is it incorrect to say that a machine is "at rest" when it is not moving ?  I'd tend to use "at rest" for living organisms and use something like "not in motion" for machines and devices, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Dictionaries provide example sentences. I had to try four before I found a relevant example (with a non-living subject referent) (in [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/at-rest)).

Comment: Perhaps the best known instance of "at rest" applied to inanimate things is [Newton's first law of motion](https://todayinsci.com/N/Newton_Isaac/NewtonIsaac-PerseveresMotionQuote800px.htm) (as translated into English, from Latin).

Comment: "idle" is a usual adjective to mean "at rest" (both for machines and people).

Comment: "At rest" has an established meaning in physics.

Comment: "at rest" means not accelerated; "not in motion" means not in motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diffrence between at rest and not in motion is that at rest was metaphorical meanings. at rest could mean dead or calm like your sleeping forever and your mind is calm at your emotions "resting".

Here are the google definitions for at rest.

- not moving or exerting oneself.
- not agitated or troubled; tranquil.
  "if you think something's wrong, consult the doctor and put your mind at rest"
- dead and buried.

Not moving is only the literal definition for at rest, and nothing more. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nonmoving